# Binary format issue when writing to file

Tags: tcl

Below there is a trivial script writing a byte to a file:

```
set wf [open "test.bin" "w"]
set int_result 0x80
puts -nonewline $wf [binary format c [expr {$int_result}]]
close $wf
exit
```

Surprisingly, the file will contain 0x3F, not 0x80.
Can anybody explain what is happening?

Thanks a lot,
Dmitry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl prefers to read and write text files by default, which means it does a number of transformations on the data for you both going into Tcl and going out to a file. When working with binary data, you want these switched off. Either use `wb` instead of `w` in the call to `open` (just like in C stdio's `fopen()` call), or use `fconfigure` to put the channel into binary mode after opening it.

```
set wf [open "test.bin" wb]
```

```
set wf [open "test.bin" w]
# It's the -translation option for historical/backward-compatibility reasons
fconfigure $wf -translation binary
```

They're equivalent; the `b` makes `open` call (the implementation of) `fconfigure` internally to set exactly that option.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix: use

```
open test.bin wb
```

to open the file in binary mode.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter, it works indeed! So pity that I didn't know about it and wasted 2.5 hours.